# GCP - Not able to list objects inside Bucket even having devstorage.read_only permission?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created a EC2 instance, which creates by default service account with default permissions. So when I checked the default permissions I found that the service account is all these permissions below.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
```

Now I tried to list all the objects inside the bucket by using the command:-

`gsutil ls gs://mybucketname`

Found an error

`AccessDeniedException: 403 XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.`

Why I am getting this error even though my service account user is having `devstorage.read_only`?

And I am very new to GCP here, so let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the official documentation regarding the difference between setting the service account level of access with IAM roles and setting the GCE instance's access scopes:

[Service account permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)

> When you set up an instance to run as a service account, you determine
> the level of access the service account has by the IAM roles that you
> grant to the service account. If the service account has no IAM roles,
> then no API methods can be run by the service account on that
> instance.
>
> Furthermore, an instance's access scopes determine the default OAuth
> scopes for requests made through the gcloud tool and client libraries
> on the instance. As a result, access scopes potentially further
> **limit access to API methods** when authenticating through OAuth. However, they do not extend to other authentication protocols like
> gRPC.
>
> Essentially:
>
> IAM **restricts access to APIs based on the IAM roles** that are granted
> to the service account.
>
> Access scopes **potentially further limit
> access to API methods** when authenticating through OAuth.

Therefore I would recomend [to add an IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-gcloud-manual) with `storage.objects.list` permission to your instance service account (maybe `roles/storage.legacyBucketReader`).

Comment: Yup! Got a clear picture. I was confused with Roles and IAM user. Now this gives a clear picture about it. I moved from AWS to GCP so was lillte confusde

Comment: hi @marian.vladoi can you help me in this question:- 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073267/i-am-not-able-to-access-compute-engine-api-with-gcloud

Comment: @user2300940 Solve what? S