# I am not able to access compute engine API with gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-compute-api

I have an instance running with access scope 'Set Access for each API', and explicitly allowing Compute Engine API with Read-Write access as showing in this below image.

[API access list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ULjQ.png)

So I logged inside the instance via SSH, and I tried to run this command:-

`gcloud compute instances list`

and I got an error:

`- Required 'compute.zones.list' permission for 'projects/dotted-hxxl-xxx'`

My user is having explicitly allowing access to compute Engine API but still I am getting the error. I shouldn't get this error right? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

when you are logged into an instance, the permissions that you get aren't these of your users but these of the compute engine [provided by the metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata).

- Go to the compute engine detail and have a look to the Service Account section.
- If there is a service account, check the permissions of it
- If not, add a service account on your VM (you will need to stop it to perform this operation)

Comment: hi, for checking the permissions you mean the IAM policies right?, I did, and it has only 'Storage List Objects'. So do you mean, I need to give permission for it, explicitly,?

Comment: perform a `gcloud config list`, you will see the service account of your VM. And then grant the required permissions on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. stop the compute engine instance

`gcloud compute instances stop instance-1 --zone us-central1-c`

2. get the service account of the instance

`gcloud compute instances describe instance-1 --zone us-central1-c | grep email`

3. assign the role `roles/compute.instanceAdmin` to the service account

`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding your_project -- member="serviceAccount:SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID@your_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/compute.instanceAdmin"`

4. start the instance

`gcloud compute instances start instance-1 --zone us-central1-c`

5. ssh to the instance

`gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone us-central1-c`

6. run the gcloud command

`gcloud compute instances list`

Also read about the difference between [IAM roles  and OAuth scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)

> When you set up an instance to run as a service account, you determine
> the level of access the service account has by the IAM roles that you
> grant to the service account. If the service account has no IAM roles,
> then no API methods can be run by the service account on that
> instance.
>
> Furthermore, an instance's access scopes determine the default OAuth
> scopes for requests made through the gcloud tool and client libraries
> on the instance. As a result, access scopes potentially further limit
> access to API methods when authenticating through OAuth

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, correct me if I am wrong, IAM roles assigned the permission on service accounts, and Oauth scopes defined the scopes to which they (means service account) can access. If IAM instance admin is allowed on service account but the scope is default scope, so gcloud can't get the results, right?

Comment: No, gcloud will get the results if IAM is allowed on service account and default scope. You can just restrict the sevice account with scope. For example, only if I create a VM with default compute engine service account, then I will be able to restrict the access with scope. If I create a VM with a custom service account, then I can use only the default scope.

Comment: also please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103633/what-happens-when-re-authenticating-the-service-account-with-gcloud/65115204#65115204)