# What happens when re-authenticating the service account with gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, google-iam

I have heard that if the service account is having high privileges, but access scopes are restrictive, and we need to somehow authenticate to services without OAuth, then we can re-authenticate the service account with the keys that we have (assuming we got somehow).

So is it true, re-authenticating the service account can give us cloud-platform scopes?

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json`

Comment: By default, you have the Cloud Platform scope. What's your issue? What do you expect or need?

Comment: But I have seen that it doesn't set default scope as Cloud Platform Scope, it takes this scope as default:-  `Allow default access` which contains default permissions, and cloud platform is:- `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: On your computer or on Compute Engine?

Comment: On Compute Engine, 

Oh did you mean if I try to reauthenticate my service account on my computer where gcloud installed, it will take bydefault cloud-platform scope?

see, I am very new to GCP so yeah I am definitely missing something.

Comment: No problem, everyone have started a day! On your computer, yes, you have the Cloud Platform scope by default. But I recommend you to never (or in specific case only) service account key file. On your computer, use `gcloud auth login` command. On compute engine, you have the metadata server that provide you the credential of the service account set in the configuration. Be careful, by default, on compute engine, all the scope aren't allowed! So, go ahead, you will have some blocking point. Come back here and ask your questions when you have issues. It's normal at the beginning!

Comment: What's your goal with the cloud-platform scopes ? Do you need any more explanation than the one Guillaume provided ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I saw in GCP, thanks @guillaumeblaquiere for this detailed perfect reply. It really really helps. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes are an OAuth permission mechanism. Google Cloud first started with "Scopes" as the permission method before IAM was developed.

Service Accounts do not use scopes in a way that you manage unless you are writing your own authorization code. Service Accounts use IAM Roles for permission control. You can specify scopes when writing low-level code, but that is not necessary or recommended.

Google Compute Engine originally used OAuth scopes for permissions and still offers that feature. Compute Engine Scopes limit the permissions assigned to the service account assigned to Compute Engine. Scopes do not add permissions to the service account.

For the following command"

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
```

If you run this command on your desktop or in Compute Engine, you are telling the CLI and tools developed with the SDK to use the specified service account for authorization. The scope "cloud-platform" does not matter here. The IAM roles assigned to the service account determine permissions. The scopes that you assigned to the instance are not used by this command. Only the credentials located in the Compute Engine instance metadata (the original credentials) continue to be affected by scopes.

Summary:

Scopes are a legacy authorization mechanism. IAM is the preferred and required authentication method meaning you must set permissions via IAM Roles. Scopes cannot do that for you. You can mix the two but I do not recommend that. Use the scope cloud-platform and control authorization via IAM Roles.

A service account with the scope "cloud-platform" and no IAM Roles has NO permissions.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and very informative reply. It helps. Thanks a lot :) Have to accept it. :)